# Lock device orientation for SwiftUI UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, swiftui-navigationview, uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

I have a UIViewController that I need to wrap and use as a SwiftUI view. I have implemented the methods needed to lock device orientation for that view controller. When I use the UIViewController in an UIKit context, the orientation could be locked.

```html
class ContentViewController : UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .portrait
    }
    
    override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return .portrait
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

When I wrap it as a SwiftUI view with UIViewControllerRepresentable, the orientation could not be locked. The

```html
struct ContentWrappedView : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ContentViewController {
        return ContentViewController.init()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ContentViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Is this expected behavior? Is there a way around it?
I'll be using it in a framework and so, implementing it with AppDelegate doesn't work for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also have this problem, did you find a workaround?